# UITableViewCell subviews issue

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I load cell from xib. I added 3 vertical separators to the cell (tried to add from xib and from code). Everything is OK until I select the cell. When I select the sell, separators disappear.

Here are the images:
Not selected:
[image]

Selected
[image]

Code of adding separators:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.topSeparator = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 1)] autorelease];
        [self addSubview:topSeparator];

        self.bottomSeparator = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height - 1, self.bounds.size.width, 1)] autorelease];
        [self addSubview:bottomSeparator];

        // Initialization code
        CGFloat xOffset = 314;
        UIView *imageView1 = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, 1, self.bounds.size.height)] autorelease];
        imageView1.tag = kTagBorder1;
        imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self addSubview:imageView1];

        xOffset = 487;
        imageView1 = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, 1, self.bounds.size.height)] autorelease];
        imageView1.tag = kTagBorder2;
        imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self addSubview:imageView1];

        xOffset = 573;
        imageView1 = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset, 0, 1, self.bounds.size.height)] autorelease];
        imageView1.tag = kTagBorder3;
        imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self addSubview:imageView1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I even tried this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:[self viewWithTag:kTagBorder1]];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:[self viewWithTag:kTagBorder2]];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:[self viewWithTag:kTagBorder3]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I used UIImageView with black image instead of uiview with black background. In this case view doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the lines as a child view of `self` (`UITableViewCell`). Instead, add it as a child of `self.contentView` - which is the view containing the components inside a `UITableViewCell`.

[This article contains tips on how to customize a UITableView properly](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).